# Unable capture full screen shot of the webpages

Tags: javascript, selenium-chromedriver

I have written the javascript code to capture the entire web page.

when I'm running the script on windows platform via Eclipse IDE. The screenshot is not captured properly, please refer to the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ674.png).

Please find the code:

```
Screenshot Screenshot = new AShot()
                              .shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportRetina(100, 0, 0, 2))
                              .takeScreenshot(driver);
```

Please let me know what should be the exact resolution to use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not giving "**AShot()**" enough time to capture the whole web page.

To take the full page screenshot of a page AShot() scrolls down the page at particular time intervals “1000 ms” till the bottom of the page and takes the screenshot of the entire page.

Using shootingStrategy() method Ashot() takes the entire page screenshot. The syntax is:

```
new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(1000)).takeScreenshot(WebDriver driver);
```

The code is to save the screenshot in the desired location-

```
ImageIO.write(RebderedImage im, String Image format, String File Output);
```

You have to adjust as per your requirement.

Comment: Hi There, Thank you so much! But this code is not printing as expected two things I'm getting a problem one is left content is missing and below content also not visible properly. Is there way paly around viewportRetina(100, 0, 0, 2)) code.